# ASP.NET Detect dynamic file request

Tags: asp.net, events

How to detect any success in any of the events in "Global.asax"in "Request" only the files that are dynamic (aspx, ascx, ashx, ...) non dynamic (css, js, txt, .. .).

I know I can check the file extension like this:

File Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ext = Request.FilePath.Split('.')[1];
    string[] arExt = {"aspx", "ascx", "ashx"};

    for (int i = 0; i < arExt.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arExt[i] == ext) 
        {
           // my code
        }
    }

}
```

But I wonder if there is any other way to identify dynamic vs static requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that any code will only be executed on a dynamic request.  Any static requests will be dealt with by IIS and only redirected to a dynamic request for security / session reasons.